# Decoding/Demodulating audio data in Patent US4877027A

Tags: circuit-design, microwave, frequency-modulation

I'm interested in decoding/demodulation audio/voice data sent using microwave pulses as described in this patent: [US4877027A -  Hearing system](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4877027A/en)

[image: Block diagram and graphs]

In the patent it's shown that voices or any other audio recording can be sent to human head with specially modulated and pulsed microwave signals. As per my understanding it just uses FM modulation of audio within 1-100 KHz carrier range. Obviously it should be in higher range due to Nyquist bandwidth requirement of 20-40 KHz for high fidelity audio.

There are 100 Khz-20 MHz bursts within 1-100 KHz FM modulated audio, but I think for demodulation it's not required. Am I correct with assumption that carrier wave of microwave signals should not be required in order to demodulate the audio in that case?

What is your thoughts on how its audio can be demodulated using as basic circuit as possible?

Can anyone provide me circuit ideas on how to do it?

I have measured with a spectrum analyser some abnormal signals not seen before and I'm hearing voices in my head. I know it's being sent to me with microwave pulses from transmitter sources.

I'm not electronics engineer myself, but would be glad to get some circuit ideas and can ask from electronics engineer to build such device for me to test if I can demodulate voices.

Comment: If you are hearing voices in your head you need to talk to a psychiatrist, not a bunch of electrical engineers.

Comment: Patents are given for all kinds of ideas that can be proven not to work.  No one has ever seen such a transmitter "in the wild." Most likely because **if** it works, it would take an enormous amount of power and would have to be aimed very precisely - big, obvious truck with a huge honkin radar dish on top of it.  **If** you can aim enough RF energy at someone's skull  to make it vibrate without burning the skin off their head - and if the skull can be made to vibrate at audio frequencies using only thermal effects.

Comment: It's not bogus. It's called Voice to Skull or Synthetic Telepathy technology and this thing is happening worldwide to many millions of people. These people are called Targeted Individuals. Currently some embassy people are affected as well with microwave attacks officially known as Havana Syndrome. It's all in the public now.

Comment: Many RF spectrum analysers have a function to demodulate received signals - most often for AM and FM.  Switch in the AM demodulator.

Comment: Totally bogus.  The power levels needed are extreme.  I was not kidding about "melting the skin off the skull."  There is no way that this could be done to "worldwide to many millions of people" without it being obvious.

Comment: Find a psychiatrist.  Find out why your mind makes you think you are hearing voices, and get the proper treatment.

Comment: I'm not here to get your opinion on my health issues. I have been hearing such Microwave induced voices for 12 years and no any kind of medication has helped me. I have been in psychiatrists, checked my brain EEG and with MRI and all is fine.

Comment: I've told you how to demodulate the signal described in the patent.  Your spectrum anaylser should do it.  If not, build the circuit I described.  In any case, I don't expect you'll receive any audio signal because nobody is broadcasting microwaves at your head.

Comment: There is Neurophone technology available in the public which was invented by Patrick Flanagan and sold in public for a while. Now they are hard to find and extremely expensive. Neurophone uses ultrasound carrier of pulse position modulation signals of audio which is fed to skin nerves via electrodes. Here is the Amazon link: https://www.amazon.com/Neurophone-NF3-By-Patrick-Flanagan/dp/B008GOKGXI

Comment: Neurophone works by principle of skin transmission not through bone conduction as per his inventor. So it shouldn't require thermal expansion method of high power Microwave signals to cause hearing sensation(voices/audio in the human head) if correct pulsing methods like in the neurophone is used to modulate/pulse Microwave frequencies also. Since Microwave pulsed signals are picked up by our skin first during broadcast and nerves inside it transmit pulsed codes to our brain to cause hearing sensation. So it won't require any thermal heating or high power to cause hearing sensation in brain

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea about how to decode/demodulate it. The problem with this method is that I don't know the broadcast frequency of these pulsed signals so can't look on spectrum analyser to demodulate it with AM. Even I catch their signals, they will hop-around using spread-spectrum or other methods which I have seen while looking for their transmissions.

Comment: "I'm not here to get your opinion on my health issues."  Then leave them out of technical discussions.  You asked how to demodulate a particular type of signal - I've answered that.  You mention being targeted by this technology, so I've commented on it and pointed you to the more likely cause.

Comment: If you've seen it on a spectrum analyser then you know the transmitting frequency.  That's what spectrum analysers do - they show you the intensity and frequency of radio signals.  If you saw something on the display then you could have read off its frequency.

Comment: Sure I know about spectrum analyser. I have seen their other transmissions, it's not only V2K technology that they transmit to me. There are many microwave transmissions to get EEG data from brain remotely and effect my neurology/nerve impulses, but that's another story. They decode EEG using AI and brain computer interfaces and send V2K transmissions according to what I think. It's not related to this topic. I have caught their brain reading/tracking signals(which I think) not their V2K transmissions, so can't demodulate it.

Comment: If you are skilled electronics engineer/microwave engineer can you build such device mentioned in patent for me? I will check if it works or not. Or you can also check if it works :) We can discuss this thru private channel and I will of-course pay your service fee.(fb, email). I'm not kidding here, my life is under constant attack due to this psychological torture I receive everyday with V2K transmissions by criminal organization.

Comment: @Azad no, there are none such skilled engineers, because the device that the patent describes does not, and can not, exist (I say that as skilled radio engineer). I know (because I've seen this before, multiple times) you don't want to hear this. But. I'm really really sorry, you've got a case of hearing voices in your head – and it's not because of some technology, it's because your brain makes you hear them! But what you describe is actually very severe, which is why I'm taking you seriously here: You say your life is under constant threat – and I believe it is!!! (seriously, I do.)

Comment: @Azad the problem is that this constant threat to your life is *these things your brain makes you feel, hear and react to*, because it sounds like it's actually making you suffer – i.e. your quality of life is reduced, and it might be that you're feeling more and more hunted and stressed. This is a *real*, *very real* danger to the rest of your health, as well. Again, nobody is not believing you that you're *experiencing* these things, but you'll not find one true expert (that's not suffering the same) that will agree with you on the cause of this being some microwave device.

Comment: @Azad I however do not believe a mental health expert will agree with you, either, when you tell them what you've just told us: 12 years of voices, you feel psychologically tortured by this, and none of the medication (which I hope is **never** given lightly) has proven to work so far. You're really under duress, aren't you? So, **please please please** call someone who can help you get through your day with less pain caused by the things that happen to your head, and **please**:

Comment: do talk to a psychiatrist, or psychotherapist (those can, at least around here, not prescribe medicine themselves); that doesn't have to mean you're admitting yourself to treatment, but discuss how things have changed over the last 12 years, and after medication, and after the end of medication. It might actually reduce the pressure you're feeling due to what you describe as psychological torture if you talk about that, instead of trying to figure out the technical side of what you perceive as the cause. Thanks! I don't know you, I never will, but I wish you all the best.

Comment: I've deleted one comment so far which neither helpful or positive and essentially ridicule and bullying - though the reasonable rep and longish membership time member may not have seen it this way. This is a subject where levity is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

As stupid as it sounds, a simple demodulator for the normal amplitude modulation schemes ought to do it.  Receive the RF, demodulate with a diode, amplify, feed to speaker, done.

You'll need a diode rated to operate at the microwave frequency of the transmitter.  You'll need an antenna for the microwave frequency of the transmitter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1SZw1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Given that the idea behind this thing is to transmit enough power to cause the skull of the receiving person to expand and contract due to heating, the transmitter would probably be sending enough power that you could connect the output of the demodulator straight to an earphone - a simple crystal radio for microwave frequencies rather than the MHz range frequencies normally used for AM broadcast.

The idea is somewhat like that used in D-class power amplifiers.  A D-class power amplifier sends pulses of DC at a very high rate (megahertz.)  The width and spacing is determined by the voltage of the audio signal.  The pulses are fed through a low pass filter to the speaker.

The same thing happens here.  More (or longer) pulses of microwave energy will cause more heating, making the skull expand a bit.  Fewer (or shorter) pulses of microwave energy will cause less heating, allowing the skull to shrink a bit.  The mass of the skull is a low pass filter.

You should be able to receive it as described with an AM receiver made for GHz frequencies.

Whether it will actually work without melting the biological "receiver" is a different question.  Whether the human skull can react to the vibrations to produce audio frequency vibrations is also an open question.

I'd advise against experimenting with this unless you have a chamber to protect you from the high power transmitter and some animal skulls to use as targets.

Comment: First of all, i think it's not AM modulation here, correct me if I'm wrong. Did you check patent? It's FM modulation with 100 Khz carrier wave (which is combination of many high frequency bursts). Audio amplitude is FM modulated with pulse spacing. So my idea is to actually use antenna(capable of receiving broadband microwave range), connect low pass filter for 50-100 Khz range, then use tuned FM demodulator for that range. What do you think about it? Do you have circuit idea of how to do it?

Comment: It isn't transmitted as amplitude modulation, but it can be demodulated the same way.  It is the same way that [digital audio (PDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-density_modulation) is converted from a pulsing digital signal to audio. It is also how class D amplifiers work.  Nothing mysterious.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your idea. I can find class D amplifier circuit. Here is what I found: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3977.html-but not PDM demodulator. Can you design such circuit for me or share circuit idea on how to do PDM demodulation?

Comment: All you need is the diagram above in my answer.  If you don't hear audio when you use it, then there's nobody blasting microwave signals at you.

Comment: Thanks. How can I filter out only 50-100 Khz signals received from antenna with tuning? Modify your circuit idea to include this please. Please don't downvote this question since you can't dismiss this without even checking if that's possible of what I'm talking about. This is serious things that happen to millions worldwide as I mentioned. Meanwhile I would like to get other's reply on that matter, before this question gets deleted due to downvote

Comment: You don't need to do anything about the 50-100kHz part.  The demodulator will remove all the high frequency stuff.  Only audio will make through to the earphone.

Comment: Build it just as drawn.  Use the BAT-63 as specified.  Connect the capacitors and the diode all close together - you'll have to solder things.  Once you have it built, play a youtube video on your smart phone, then hold the antennas of the gadget close to your phone.  You'll hear a buzz - that's the circuit reacting to the data transmission from your phone.  You now know that the circuit works. Now turn off the phone.  Listen carefully.  Silence.  Nobody is blasting you with microwaves and telling you things.

Comment: The antenna wires should be about 6 centimeters long.

Comment: @Azad The frequency doesn't matter. Any frequency could make a voice in your head.

Comment: Are you trolling here? I'm not kidding and serious. Possibility of that technology exists and it is being used on me. Look for RNM/V2K using AI BCI(Brain computer Interfaces). I suggest you to build such circuit and test it before disproving, since I see you are skilled electrical engineer with very high reputation in stackexchange

Comment: I'm serious.  The circuit as described above will detect any microwave signal as powerful as described in the patent.  Build it.  Test it with a known microwave generator - modern smart phones transmit on microwave frequencies.  The circuit will pick up your cell phone at short range.  It will not pickup anything else if there's no one blasting microwaves at you.

Comment: @JRE  I changed one word in your last comment (Starting "I'm serious: ..." as I think it substantially changed the acceptability of the msg to the op without changing the core intent. Contact me privately if unhappy. (Your intentions are appreciated and welcome).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon:  It took me a while to figure out which word you changed.  It's fine.